# Typing pipe compose function that uses reduceRight with generics

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

A while ago a friendly stack overflow user [helped me to solve to get a compose function to work properly with TypeScript generics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64409038/use-generics-to-get-a-typed-result-of-my-little-compose-function?rq=1).

```
type OuterFunction<OA, OR> = (arg: OA) => OR;
type InnerFunction<IA extends unknown[], IR> = (...args: IA) => IR;

const compose = <T extends unknown[], V, W>(
  outer: OuterFunction<V, W>,
  inner: InnerFunction<T, V>
) => (...innerParams: T) => outer(inner(...innerParams));
```

This works great. So the resulting composed function has the arguments type of inner function and the return type of outer function, and correctly expects outer functions arguments to match inner functions return type.

And here is my pipe function utilizing that same compose with reduceRight, allowing to define functions from more than two other functions:

```
const pipe = (...functions: any[]) =>
  functions.reduceRight((prev, curr) => compose(prev, curr));
```

This runs and works JavaScript wise as expected. Types are, obviously, completely vanishing when done like this.

I was fiddling and doing more different ways than I can remember and it also doesn't really make sense to list them up here, because none of them worked at all. They all did not even compile, or only resulted in non types just as the basic version above.

Here this is in a TypeScript playground of this:
https://tsplay.dev/w62jEw

#### How does fp-ts do this?

I looked at how [fp-ts does this with their pipe](https://github.com/gcanti/fp-ts/blob/c14617d881449bf7c1dde27d6a9ebb18479e0c97/src/function.ts#L678), and concluded that their solution will work very well, but is not as nice as using reduceRight (it is basically a huge overload cascade they do to achieve it).

Since piping > 18 functions together is actually not a scenario I have to expect as quite common, my fiddling for that solution is actually redundant.

But perhaps there is a nice solution out there, and in that case it might be interesting for even more than just myself to know about it ;)

---

TIA for any hints.

Comment: Working playground link: https://tsplay.dev/w62jEw

Answer (score 1):

With [Variadic Tuple Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#variadic-tuple-types), which are new feature in TypeScript 4.0, you can do the following:

```typescript
type Func = (...args: any) => any
declare function pipe<T extends Func, U extends Func, R extends Func>
    (...functions: [T, ...U[], R]) : (...args: Parameters<T>) => ReturnType<R>;
```

*Variadic Typle Types* let you define `...functions` array as `[T, ...U[], R]` and then use first and last function signatures (`T` and `R`) to extract input and return parameters.

Full example would look like this:

```typescript
const onePlus = (a: number): number => a + 1;
const asString = (a: number): string => `${a}`;
const toInt = (a: string): number => Number.parseInt(a, 10);


type Func = (...args: any) => any
declare function pipe<T extends Func, U extends Func, R extends Func>
    (...functions: [T, ...U[], R]) : (...args: Parameters<T>) => ReturnType<R>;

const pipeWorks = pipe(
  onePlus,
  asString,
  toInt,
  onePlus,
  asString,
  toInt,
  onePlus
);

console.log(pipeWorks(1));
```

Or in the TS playground [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBOCmAFANgVwjAvDAFAQwC4YxUBbAI3gCcBKIki6rAPhjxgGoYBGAbgChQkWHggBlKFQCWYAOZZchYmUq0i0aXJYwABgBIA3ngC%20OgUOgwoIAJJhY2fOskzZdZYyraAciuoA6AAc8Kgh4Oyh8ABoeAAYaAX5%20KABPQPgYADFUMGAFHH9CkNkIIjwwFJptcpT%20ABN4YGQQjIAzHOAoKXAYQKl0gB4AFRh4AA8oeDA6jGzcmIBVUYmpmayOmIAlZcnp2Y7mAsL23K7wUpgAbSGYwv8Fy4BdLceqoiP-YovEELxSeEmoWGzCqmFYmwBqCoYCGaXgA02zESFlgfXSAHUQFQANYYbBo%20A4fgwOBgJBoCBRYlscQuORUknWCIM0nk9As0QSTSyFlM%20wshAodD8BJJCwgZDwfzIECyHAEzE4iA4bg0BJAA).

If you leave only two pipe-functions:

```typescript
const pipeWorks = pipe(
  onePlus,
  asString
);
```

`pipeWorks` function signature will be `(a: number) => string`.

However, note that this `pipe` function signature only picks input parameters of first function `T` and return parameter of the last function `R`. It **does not type check** any in-between function, if their signatures (input/output parameters) can be chained or not.

You would probably have to constrain `Func` type a bit more, to ensure chaining signatures are valid.

Comment: unfortunately it turns out it doesn't work for me? How did it work for you?

Because for me the playground example you made doesn't run, and I also think I can see why: It doesn't include a function body and does not use compose.

Comment: Yes, I used playground only for type-checking. You wrote that your function implementation works fine, but that you loose types, so I just gave you correct function signature from TypeScript point of view. Stich your working implementation inside (and remove `declare` keyword).

Comment: Yes, type wise it works for me too. But when I try to stitch it inside it won't work for me: https://tsplay.dev/mbkVEW

Comment: I mean it runs, JavaScript wise, but TypeScript is not happy: `Type 'ComposedFunction<any, any>' is not assignable to type 'T | U | R'.` I fiddled with that around in different ways. That is pretty much where my ComposedFunction type came from.

Comment: Also trying to fiddle in the compose function directly did not bring me any type wise working outcome: https://tsplay.dev/mA7z8w

Comment: I mean I really appreciate your solution. I somehow just don't manage to get the stitching done here... Your solution would be great for me.

Comment: Your initial solution for `compose` is overcomplicated from my point of view. Also, your `pipe` function only works if subsequent functions accept only one parameter and return one parameter. So it somehow works for your current usage, but it's not type-safe at all. Of course, you can always "force" the return type, but it's not proper solution.

Comment: Here is the version of `pipe` that works with your initial approach by forcing the function signature: https://tsplay.dev/wXR41m In my opinion, even though this works, it's the wrong way to go.

Comment: In plain JS the combination of my compose and pipe work great. What you state about the in between function only being allowed to take one argument is not correct, since arguments are always spread by compose. I used it quite often actually, and it worked fine for me.
I found another good real world solution for my problem though: https://github.com/simontonsoftware/s-libs/blob/master/projects/micro-dash/src/lib/util/flow-right.ts#L17
It seems micro-dash does it with reduce, but types it with lots of overloads. This seems like a sattisfying solution. Thx lots for your help!

Comment: If, in your original example, you redefine `const onePlus = (a: number, b: number): number => a + b;` and call `console.log(pipeWorks(1, 2))` it will return `NaN`, because `onePlus` appears at 4th and 7th position as well - https://tsplay.dev/m02Xqw
I agree, it's better to use tested library, to avoid all potential pitfalls. You're welcome.

Comment: Yea, sure, if args of the in-between won't match with what their inner returns it obviously can't work. I meant by worked fine old school JS-be-aware-of-types-yourself-works ;-). So I had to know what to stack together.  But then It was quite neat for me, in many occasions.
Yea, going for a lib is most certainly better.
I could also think of just dropping the flow/pipe/whatever luxury, and define such a chain just in multiple declarations using my compose. I think that can me more explicit anyway and would work fully just as I have it now.

Answer (score 1):

After several attempts, I have this solution.

```js
type Func = (...args: any) => any

function pipe<T extends Func, U extends Func[], R extends Func>
    (...fns: [T, ...U, R]): (x: Parameters<T>[number]) => ReturnType<R> {
        return (x) => fns.reduce((y, f) => f(y), x as Parameters<T | U[number] | R>);
    }

const add1 = (x: number) => x + 1;
const add2 = (x: number) => x + 2;
const add3 = (x: number) => x + 3;
const add4 = (x: number) => x + 4;
const add10 = pipe(add1, add2, add3, add4); // all same type works
console.log(add10(2));

const mix = pipe(add1, String, Number); // mix type works
console.log(mix(2));
```

You can hover your mouse over `pipe` and see correct type inference, because by using [Variadic Tuple Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#variadic-tuple-types), generic `U` is a tuple which contains middle function signatures.

Further Reading: I find this [blog](https://fettblog.eu/variadic-tuple-types-preview/) very well written about Variadic Tuple Types.

**Updated:**

If you want the first function to accept mutiple parameters, you have to revise the function body like below, though types are quite similar

```js
const pipe2 = <T extends Func, U extends Func[], R extends Func>
    (...fns: [T, ...U, R]): (...args: Parameters<T>) => ReturnType<R> => 
        fns.reduce((f, g) => 
            (...args: [...Parameters<T>]) => g(f(...args)));
```

However this technique cannot handle zero or one parameter. We need to add function overloading to make it more general.

```js
type Func = (...args: any) => any
type Noop = () => void;
const noop: Noop = () => {};

function pipe2(): Noop;
function pipe2<T extends Func>(fn: T): T;
function pipe2<T extends Func, U extends Func[], R extends Func>(...fns: [T, ...U, R]): (...args: Parameters<T>) => ReturnType<R>;
function pipe2(...fns: any) {
    if (fns.length === 0) return noop;
    if (fns.length === 1) return fns[0];
    return fns.reduce((f: any, g: any) =>
        (...args: any) => g(f(...args))
    );
}

const addxy = (x: number, y: number) => x + y;
const add1 = (x: number) => x + 1;
const add2 = (x: number) => x + 2;
const add3 = (x: number) => x + 3;
const noopAgain = pipe2();
const addxyAgain = pipe2(addxy);
const addxyAnd1 = pipe2(addxy, add1);
const addxyAnd1And2 = pipe2(addxy, add1, add2);
const addAll = pipe2(addxy, add1, add2, add3);
const mix = pipe2(addxy, String, Number);
console.log(addxyAgain(2, 3)); // -> 5
console.log(addxyAnd1(2, 3)); // -> 6
console.log(addxyAnd1And2(2, 3)); // -> 8
console.log(addAll(2, 3)); // -> 11
console.log(mix(2, 3)); // -> 5
```

Comment: But I think when piping, you should curry all the functions first, instead of accept multiple arguments of the first function